# Declare SQL Variables in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, variables

I have a SQL Query that I am trying to add to Powershell so that I can setup a routine to export a CSV file. The SQL works great:

```
declare @firstdayfilter datetime;
declare @lastdayfilter datetime;
declare @SalesDate  date;

set @firstdayfilter = (select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0));
set @lastdayfilter = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()));
set @SalesDate = (select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0));

select @firstdayfilter ,@lastdayfilter ,@SalesDate
```

When I move this into a Powershell file, I get an error when I try to declare the variable. I've tried many different iterations to no success. I am a noob at Powershell.

Here's what I had originally (for the first field).

```
$FirstDayFilter = @"
 Declare @firstdayfilter datetime ;
 set @firstdayfilter = (select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0));
"@

$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT 
 $FirstDayFilter
"@
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 
'Declare'."
At S:\Common\Active IT Projects\Projects\OrionSales\OrionCPIMTDSalesReport.ps1:277 char:5
+     $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) #| Out-Null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

So what am I missing? I know other fields work. For example if I set $FirstDayFilter = "Test" it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT 
 $FirstDayFilter
"@
```

Produces this string:

```
SELECT 
Declare @firstdayfilter datetime ;
 set @firstdayfilter = (select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0));
```

...which is not valid SQL. Maybe you meant:

```
$SqlQuery = @"
 $FirstDayFilter
 SELECT @FirstDayFilter
"@
```

Comment: That was my problem. Thank you.